# MS Access update by joining fields from 2 tables when lookup table has more than one match

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

for MS Access, if I have the following 2 tables which I would like to update the value of **[Tbl1]![B]** by linking the fields **"A"** together between the 2 tables, and lookup the value of **"B"** from **Tbl2,** how exactly does Access determine which value to select as B?

**Tbl1**

```
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
|  111 |   ?  |
|  222 |   ?  |
+------+------+
```

**Tbl2**

```
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
|  111 |  AAA |
|  111 |  BBB |
|  222 |  CCC |
|  222 |  DDD |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your trying to have a lookup table for a main table. If so this is how you do it so that when you update the lookup table, all the values in the main table update.

```
Go to design view for the Main Table(tbl2)
Go to the field(A) that will be linked to the lookup table.
The data type for this field should be number.
Click on the tab "Lookup".
Change [Display Control] to "Combo Box"
Set [Row Source Type] to "Table/Query"
Set [Row Source] = "SELECT A, B From TBL1"
Set [Column Count] = 2
Set [Column Widths] = 0;10
```